# Git rebase - i squashing didn't remove commit

Tags: git, github, commit, rebase, squash

I have a local commit after origin master's head, and want to combine last two commits. So suppose the history is as follows:

```
* e9199ba - (HEAD -> master)
|           test
* c4e3b53 - (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
|           Saturn ring angle change in X and Y
```

And want to make one commit instead of `e9199ba` and `c4e3b53`. 
I did git  `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and squashed the second commit:

```
pick c4e3b53 Saturn ring angle change in X and Y
squash e9199ba test
```

As a result I've got two independent commits - the new squashed one and old master's one:

```
* 216b314 - (HEAD -> master)
|           Suqashed commits
| * c4e3b53 - (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
|/            Saturn ring angle change in X and Y
```

What's wrong here? Is it by the reason of the origin master's head? How to combine them in this case? Or maybe there is some history showing issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as you said:

> ... I've got two independent commits - the new squashed one and old master's one

which is what you should expect, since `git rebase` works by *copying* commits (perhaps with some modifications along the way, such as squashing), then having your Git point your own branch name to the new copies.

But `origin/master` is not your own, rebased, branch.  It's your *remote-tracking* branch, and it remembers what some *other* Git has in that *other* Git's `master`.  Hence your `origin/master` continues to remember what that other Git has, which is the original commits before you made slightly-modified copies.

That other Git repository itself—the one you call `origin`—has the other commit.  Since `origin` has it, anyone who has copied from `origin` also has it.  You must convince `origin`, and anyone who has copied from `origin`, to switch over to your shiny new commits.

If you have control over `origin`, you can likely use a "force push" to overwrite whatever it has now in its `master` with your shiny new commits.  (The `origin` repository will still have the old commit too, though perhaps very briefly until it does a "garbage collection" pass.)  Then you must also convince *all* users of `origin` to switch, too, just like you did and just like you forced `origin` to do.  Exactly *how* you can and will do that is up to you.

Note that if other people are also pushing to `origin`, it's possible that your force-push will wipe away commits *they* have added, that depend on `c4e3b53`.  You should coordinate with these other people before force-pushing.  (If there are no such other people, that makes the coordination a lot easier.)